# Eclipse not flagging errors or offerring code completion

Tags: eclipse, maven, egit, m2e

I'm working on a project that uses maven and is linked to a git repo. When I open th eegit perspective on Eclipse and try to edit a java file even if I type in complete nonsense it doesn't flag an error or offer code completion. However If i open the java perspective and try to do it everything works fine. But I don't want to use the java perspective. One another difference is how the tab bar icon looks for these 2 files.

[image: Git perspective]

[image]

The first image is in the git view, the latter is in the java perspective

Answer (score 0):

I removed the project from the workspace and re-imported it. Now it's working